# Can we determine where a Live Tile was tapped?

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I was curious if it's possible to determine, in Windows Phone 8, where in the area of a Live Tile was a tap made. So if a Live-Tile is tapped in the lower right, would we be able to somehow determine this when it passes it's function to the app? Such as maybe x,y pos, or color, offset, any info at all?

Comment: I don't think that we can do this, the Tile captures the `Tap` event without throwing it back to the app, so there's no way to know what happened before the app was launched

Comment: I see, so one would be stuck trying to pin tile groups instead of trying to capture an area. I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only information the OS gives you about the tile that was tapped is the URL that is associated to it. While it allows you to guess which tile was tapped, it doesn't give any relevant information about how the tile was tapped.

One workaround could be to use small tiles. You can simulate one medium tile by creating 4 small tiles, and you will be able to know which one of the four was tapped.

Comment: I guess this is the only current method if nothing's passed. I was hoping to simplify the user experience and pin one tile instead of 4 - 8.